# Errors Implementing jQuery UI Tabs in a Sub-Joined Data View

Tags: jquery, xslt, data-view-web-part, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement jQuery UI tabs onto my site using a subjoined data view, but I am experiencing some issues. I believe it has to do with my XSL markup, but have been hitting my head against a wall for a while now.

I have a "Category" list that is being used as a look-up list in a "Links" list. Inserting a regular subjoined data view shows all the links under their respective "Category", but the moment I apply my stylesheet, the jQuery UI Tabs don't seem to be pulling in the actual links..just the categories.

Here is my XSL markup which renders the appropriate tabs via the browser, but my child (the tab "body") elements are not being pulled in for some reason - it keeps using my dvt_empty template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
<xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="dvt_firstrow">1</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="dvt_nextpagedata" />
<xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" >


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>          
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        jQuery(function() {    
            jQuery("#tabs").tabs();  
        });  
    </script>

    <xsl:call-template name="main"/>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Categories/Rows/Row"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt.empty"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:call-template name="tabHeaders">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </ul>
                    <xsl:call-template name="tabBody">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </div>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tabHeaders">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>            
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <li><a href="#tabs-{@ID}"><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></a></li>          
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tabBody">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ParentRow" select="current()" />
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="../../../ISD_Links/Rows/Row[@Link_x0020_Category_x003a_ID=$dvt_ParentRow/@ID]" />
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)" />
    <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="$dvt_RowCount = 0" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt.empty" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                    <div id="tabs-{/dsQueryResponse/ISD_Links/Rows/Row/@Link_x0020_Category_x003a_ID}">
                             <div class="boxLink">
                                <h2><a href="{/dsQueryResponse/ISD_Links/Rows/Row/@URL}"><xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/ISD_Links/Rows/Row/@URL.desc" /></a></h2>
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/ISD_Links/Rows/Row/@Comments" /></p>
                            </div>                  
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt.empty">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_ViewEmptyText">There are no items to show in this view.</xsl:variable>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$dvt_ViewEmptyText"/></p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: Yes, I know I know I can normally use '$' instead of jQuery, but I am working with publishing page layouts where using '$' causes issues sometimes.

Additionally: via the browser control tool, I am seeing an "Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier." the moment I select another tab. I heard this could be due to incorrect markup, but it looks like my stylesheet is outputting the correct markup.

Any and all assistance in tweaking this stylesheet would be appreciated. I think I am 90% the way there, I just might be missing something obvious.

Comment: If you omit the javascript to convert it to the tabs, are you sure it is emiting the proper markup? It looks similar to other DVWPs I've created to emit markup for jQuery UI Tabs.

Comment: Yes, it's emitting the containing div with the "tabs" ID with an un-ordered list and associated divs inside.

Comment: what version of jquery and jquery ui are you using?

Comment: The CDNs are referenced in the stylesheet - jquery-1.11.1.min and 1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.

The script is working (it generates tabs for each "Category"), it appears to be my actual "divs" that are not being populated properly. SharePoint is saying there are no rows (hence the dvt_empty template being rendered), when there should be items.

I am guessing that I am calling the row items incorrectly, but I can't tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: sorry, I should have noticed. from what I see there are two probable causes. jquery ui vs jquery incompatibility, or markup misplacements. maybe you can share the actual rendered output.

Comment: after taking another look, It now seems that everything is good so perhaps you should troubleshoot the rows select instruction for the body section

Comment: Here's an image... hopefully this helps: http://oi62.tinypic.com/5vavx1.jpg